# how to create rss content encode in c# with SyndicationItem

Tags: c#, xml

i want to generate an xml feed like below in which description and content need to be in tag like
[image]

```
List<SyndicationItem> myItems = new List<SyndicationItem>();
        foreach (TestViewModel testViewModel in rssViewModel.Test)
        {
            SyndicationItem myItem = new SyndicationItem
                                         {
                                             Title = new TextSyndicationContent(testViewModel.TestTitle)

                                         };
            myItem.AddPermalink(new Uri(testViewModel.TestUrl));
            myItem.Id = testViewModel.TestUrl;
            myItem.ElementExtensions.Add(new XElement("pubDate", testViewModel.PublishedDate).CreateReader());
            foreach (TestAuthorViewModel testAuthorViewModel in testViewModel.Authors)
            {
                myItem.ElementExtensions.Add(new XElement("author", testAuthorViewModel.FullName).CreateReader());
            }
            myItem.ElementExtensions.Add(new XElement("description", string.Format("<![CDATA[{0}]]>", testViewModel.Abstract)).CreateReader());
            myItem.ElementExtensions.Add(new XElement("content", string.Format("<![CDATA[{0}]]>", testViewModel.Body)).CreateReader());
            myItems.Add(myItem);
        }
```

how will i do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the CDATA node, the you can just add it using `new XCData(content)`.

```
var xdoc = new XDocument(new XElement("Hello", new XCData("World")));
```

However, I am more concerned with the `description:encoded` and `content:encoded` tags. You are misusing namespaces, which will probably give you serious problems when using conformant xml parsers.

Comment: Thanks for the help with the CDATA node. Is there any way to create a tag like that without using a namespace

Comment: I would say no. The colon denotes an element like [namespace]:[localName] and you cannot have colons in the localName part, as far as I know. Where is this structure coming from? I would say, it is poorly designed, if it uses a construct like this.

Comment: If you are trying to actually create a valid rss file, you SHOULD NOT use this `:encoded` syntax, as is will not be part of the standard. To a valid xml parser, it does not matter if you use `<[CDATA[` or just encode things properly using entity syntax. The end result will be the same. Why do you need the `:encoded` at all?